# Animate fragment transitions with using Navigation drawer or Toolbar menu

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I have a Navigation drawer and Toolbar menu where I can go to another fragment. I used this to navigate:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
{
    drawerLayout.close()
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(
        item,
        findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
    )
}
```

How I can add custom animation while switching fragments?

---

*It is `Answer your own question`. I have faced this problem and couldn't find any answer which would work 100% well in my case so maybe this will help somebody.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the overridden method `onNavigationItemSelected` should looks:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
{
    drawerLayout.close()

    // this part checks if current fragment is the same as destination
    return if (findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).currentDestination?.id != item.itemId)
    {
        val builder = NavOptions.Builder()
            .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.enter_left_to_right)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.exit_right_to_left)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.popenter_right_to_left)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.popexit_left_to_right)

        // this part set proper pop up destination to prevent "looping" fragments
        if (item.order and Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY == 0)
        {
            var startDestination: NavDestination? =
                findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).graph

            while (startDestination is NavGraph)
            {
                val parent = startDestination
                startDestination = parent.findNode(parent.startDestination)
            }

            builder.setPopUpTo(
                startDestination!!.id,
                false
            )
        }

        val options = builder.build()
        return try
        {
            findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(item.itemId, null, options)
            true
        }
        catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) // couldn't find destination, do nothing
        {
            false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        false
    }
}
```

1. This method prevents going to current, selected fragments. So when a user is in the `Fragment A` and in the Navigation drawer again selects `Fragment A` nothing will happen, Navigation drawer will just hide.
2. This method also prevents "looping" fragments, there could be only one fragment on the stack which was selected from the Navigation drawer or Toolbar menu. E.g. in the navigation drawer is `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`. The user is in `Fragment Home` then go to `Fragment A` and next to `Fragment B`. If a user clicks back button app will go back to `Fragment Home`, not to the `Fragment A`. Also, instead of finding `startDestination` in a while loop, it is possible to use `R.id.homeFragment`. If anyone wants to allow "looping" fragments just delete this part in code.

*I have tested this solution and it seems to work well but of course there can be something which doesn't work exactly as it should.*

---

If someone wants simple animation with fade in/fade out and vertical translation:

R.anim.enter_left_to_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

R.anim.exit_right_to_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />
</set>
```

R.anim.popenter_right_to_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

R.anim.popexit_left_to_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/fragment_anim_time"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />
</set>
```

res/values/integers.xml

```
<integer name="fragment_anim_time">250</integer>
```